# Exact meaning of "parity control" in quirk

Tags: quirk

I am trying to understand [this distillation](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22:%5B%5B%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,1,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,1,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,1,1,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,1,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,1,%22zpar%22,1,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,1,1,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,1,1,1,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22H%22%5D,%5B%22Measure%22%5D,%5B%22Chance%22%5D,%5B%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22,%22Amps3%22%5D,%5B%5D,%5B%22H%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,1,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,1,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,1,1,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,1,%22zpar%22,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,1,%22zpar%22,1,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B%22zpar%22,1,1,%22zpar%22,%22%E2%88%9Ai%22%5D,%5B1,%22H%22,%22H%22,%22H%22%5D,%5B1,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22,%22Measure%22%5D,%5B1,%22Chance%22,%22Chance%22,%22Chance%22%5D,%5B%22Amps1%22,%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22,%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22,%22%7C0%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A80%7C%22%5D%5D%7D) circuit (related to [this question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/33960/15-to-1-distillation-protocol-implemented-with-lattice-surgery-dont-we-loose-t)), but I am confused by the meaning of the "parity control Z" operations represented with this symbol: [image]

The explanation in the simulator is "Include a qubit's Z observable in the column parity control. Gates in the same column only apply if an odd number of parity controls are satisfied".

Does it mean that if the the first $k$ qubits are affected with this operator, and some unitary $U$ is applied on the last $n-k$ qubit, the resulting operation is a controlled *unitary* operation only applied if the first $k$ qubits have an odd number of $1$ once the state is expanded in the computational basis?

It seems to be the case with simple examples but I don't know if I just found out particular cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean that if the the first k qubits are affected with this operator [...] a controlled unitary operation only applied if the first k qubits have an odd number of 1 once the state is expanded in the computational basis?

That's right. You can think of the parity controls as building up a multi-qubit Pauli operator, and other operations in the same column only apply in the -1 eigenspace of that operator. If all the parity controls are Z basis, this is equivalent to conditioning operations on an odd number of the parity controls being ON (in the computational basis).

Comment: Oh ok: so in different terms it corresponds to the unitary is $(1+P)/2 \otimes I + (1-P)/2 \otimes U$, where $P$ is the Pauli operator corresponding to the $X_{\text{par}}$, $Y_{\text{par}}$, $Z_{\text{par}}$ that have been put on the "control" side.

Comment: @MarcoFellous-Asiani Right.